# Entity Framework 6 Could not find the CLR type for <model>.<entity>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity

I have a web application, asp.net web-form 4.5 C# with EF6 DB-first, 
I'm working on it from almost one year, everything was working fine until today, when I've tried to add a new view to the edmx updating from the database.
The table is added with no errors, but from the code is not visible, and if I try to attach to an EntityDataSource, I get the message "**Could not find the CLR type for .**"

I've seen that the code generation strategy is set to **T4**.
If I change to "**Legacy ObjectContext**" the new entity is correctly seen in the code and EntityDataSource works fine, I can perfectly see the gridview associated, 
but if I try to navigate to some other page where I access to the other "old" entities, I get several lines of errors:

Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
**The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Report'. Previously found CLR type 'Report', newly found CLR type 'AppNameModel.Report'**.
The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Customer'. Previously found CLR type 'Customer', newly found CLR type 'AppNameModel.Customer'.
....and so on for all the previously created entities (last one is not listed and works with legacy objCtx strategy!)

So what's wrong with EF??! I've read all the Q&A on stack overflow, but none seems to have a solution.

I'll put some part of the web.config:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

...

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

here is the properties of the edmx:
[image: edmx properties]

When I add the view using T4 strategy, actually, the view is not present in any file where are defined the entity, is only displayed on the emdx visual designer. I've checked in the file .cs and in .context.cs

Please give some input, where I have to look, how can I fix...some direction! thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't yet discovered what has caused the issue, by the way I have found a workaround:

Run the **Custom Tool** on the two **.tt** files associated to your edmx.
This two files hold the auto generated code, if the auto-generation doesn't work anymore, running the custom tool you force it to update the code accordingly to your edmx model.

Comment: I just run into the same error message as you. The problem seemed to be that I had made some changes to the model classes, but had not updated the rest of the auto-generated code. Running the Custom Tool forced the update, as you mentioned, so that solved my problem as well. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to vote +1 or -1... It didn't let me undo. This particular fix didn't work for me, but I'm glad it did for someone else :) Oddly, I could still create the scaffolded views, but not the scaffolded controller.

Comment: Amazing you are ! Thank you so much! This worked for me.